# Poles of a transmission coefficient

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, singularities, s-matrix-theory, analyticity

I stumbled on the question I can't quite grasp:

What is the meaning of poles for transmission probability $T(E)$?

$$
T(E) = \left( 1+\frac{1}{4}\frac{V_0^2}{E (E+V_0)} \sin^2 \left(\frac{2 a}{\hbar }\sqrt{2m (E + V_0)}\right) \right)^{-1}
$$

$V(x)$ is a potential, $V(x) = -V_0$ for $-a<x<a$.

First of all, why this function would have any poles? Pole $z_0$ for a function $f(z)$ is by definition called a point where $f(z)$ goes to infinity (please, correct me if I am wrong. I used this [link](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pole.html) for a sanity check).

Here, on the contrary, $T(E)$ is a smooth function, for $E>V_0$ as well as for $E<V_0$ it is positive and less or equal to one.

Was this question incorrect? Did it implied other meaning for a pole?

Comment: I don't think your transmission coefficient is right. The term in the $\sin$ function isn't dimensionless. I also suspect that there should be terms like $E-V_0$, instead of $E+V_0$.

Comment: @Philip depends what is the sign of $V_0$. According to OP, potential is $-V_0$.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't notice that. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks @Philip. That was a typo, I will correct that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no pole in function $T(E)$. If $E>0$ and $V_0>0$, then denominator
$$1+\frac{1}{4}\frac{V_0^2}{E (E+V_0)} sin^2\left(\frac{2 a}{\hbar }\sqrt{2m (E + V_0)}\right)\neq 0 $$ for any value of $E$ and $V_0$. However, if,
$$\frac{2 a}{\hbar} \sqrt{2m (E + V_0)}=n\pi$$ then notice that the transmission coefficient is $1$. This means that there is perfect transmission and no reflection. The energies for this transmission is given as
$$E_n+V_0=\frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2m(2a)^2}$$ which is precisely the allowed energies for infinite square well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 

I had a typo in my initial question, so I've changed yours reply to remove my initial error)

Comment: You have already written that $T(E)$ is smooth function that is because it has no pole no matter what E is as long as it is greater than zero. So I am having a hard time understanding what your actual question is.

Comment: Let's say you have a function $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. This function will not have any poles as long as $x$ is real. That is why this function is smooth in real axis. But not smooth on complex plane.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @sslucifer. I guess the initial question "What is the meaning of the poles of T(E)" (which was part of a homework) was just simply incorrect.

Comment: The initial question was whether this $T(E)$ may have any poles and if so what they are (which I probably should have formulated better). Which as you said is impossible for the given conditions. For other situations, like scattering,  @Qmechanic posted some links which explains meaning of poles.

Answer (score 1):

For general 1D scattering (i.e. not just for the [finite potential well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well)) the poles in the [transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_coefficient) and [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_coefficient) coefficients have a physical interpretation via bound state energies, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/369913/2451).